# discord.py - self.client.session.get() doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get an image by using `await self.client.session.get()`

When I start my bot it doesn't send the error, but when I run the command it sends `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'session'`

Does anyone have any idea how I would fix this? I went looking myself and `self.client.session.get()` works fine for them

Comment: Could you share the resource(s) you're getting the code from?  What is `client.session` supposed to be?  Could you share more of your code and describe exactly how you expect it to behave?

Comment: My full code is in https://hastebin.com/wabawagogo.py It's supposed to visit a website then collect the url in the `message: LINK` bit from that website & send the embed

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, [`discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) does not have a `session` attribute.
I'm not sure who "them" is, but they are likely using a custom `Bot` subclass that has that attribute.

Comment: By "them" I just meant the other people I found doing it
I saw the error and noticed that, but I just thought I was doing something wrong